# How do I use /data modify in Minecraft 1.13.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Prior to Minecraft 1.13, the command `/entitydata` could be used to set the data on an entity. However in 1.13 this command got removed and merged into the `/data` command, [according to the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/entitydata).

However, I seem to only be able to get data using `/data get`. `/data modify set` seems to [only get introduced in 1.14](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/data#History).

Is it not possible to use `/data modify set` in 1.13(.2) at all? Seems like a huge oversight to me to remove the old command without introducing the new one.

Answer (score 2):

The 1.13 equivalent of `/entitydata` for modifying the data of a entity is `/data merge`, not `/data modify`.